# E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"

Tags: android

I am not sure where is the problem. This app is a drawing app.

The error came out is E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog" Codes are copied from Youtube. However, there are not many errors inside the codes. Esp the Button, showColordialog. The system asked me to debug the app; hope for a second opinion about this. Thank you :-)

```
package com.example.davincidrawingapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.davincidrawingapp.view.PikassoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PikassoView pikassoView;
    private AlertDialog.Builder currentAlertDialog;
    private ImageView widthImageView;
    private AlertDialog dialogLineWidth;
    private AlertDialog colorDialog;

    private SeekBar alphaSeekbar1;
    private SeekBar redSeekBar;
    private SeekBar blueSeekBar;
    private SeekBar greenSeekBar;
    private View colorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pikassoView = findViewById(R.id.view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.clearId:
                 pikassoView.clear();
                 break;

            case R.id.saveid:
                break;

            case R.id.colorid:
                showColorDialog();
                break;

            case R.id.lineWidth:
                showLineWidthDialog();
                break;

            case R.id.eraseid:
                break;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.clearId) {
            pikassoView.clear();
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void showColorDialog()
    {
        currentAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.color_dialog, null);
        alphaSeekbar1 = view.findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekbar1);
        redSeekBar= view.findViewById(R.id.redSeekbar);
        blueSeekBar= view.findViewById(R.id.blueSeekbar);
        greenSeekBar= view.findViewById(R.id.greenSeekbar);
        colorView = view.findViewById(R.id.colorView);

        //register Seekbar event listeners
        alphaSeekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
        redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
        blueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
        greenSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);

        int color = pikassoView.getDrawingColor();
        alphaSeekbar1.setProgress(Color.alpha(color));
        redSeekBar.setProgress(Color.red(color));
        greenSeekBar.setProgress(Color.green(color));
        blueSeekBar.setProgress(Color.blue(color));

        Button setColorButton = view.findViewById(R.id.setColorButton);
        setColorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pikassoView.setDrawingColor(Color.argb(
                        alphaSeekbar1.getProgress(),
                        redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                        greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                        blueSeekBar.getProgress()
                ));
             colorDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        currentAlertDialog.setView(view);
        currentAlertDialog.setTitle("Choose Color");
        colorDialog = currentAlertDialog.create();
        colorDialog.show();
    }


    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener colorSeekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        pikassoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(
                alphaSeekbar1.getProgress(),
                redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                blueSeekBar.getProgress()
        ));
            //display the current color
            colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(
                    alphaSeekbar1.getProgress(),
                    redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                    greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                    blueSeekBar.getProgress()
            ));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener widthSeekBarChange = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400,100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(pikassoView.getDrawingColor());
            p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            p.setStrokeWidth(progress);

            bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawLine(30,50, 370,50,p);
            widthImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };

    void showLineWidthDialog()
    {
        currentAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.width_dialog,null);
        final SeekBar widthSeekbar = view.findViewById(R.id.widthseekBar);
        Button setLineWidthButton = view.findViewById(R.id.widthDialogButton);
        widthImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewid);
        setLineWidthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                              {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onClick(View view)
                                                  {
                                                      pikassoView.setLineWidth(widthSeekbar.getProgress());
                                                      dialogLineWidth.dismiss();
                                                      currentAlertDialog = null;
                                                  }
                                              }
        );

        widthSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(widthSeekBarChange);
        currentAlertDialog.setView(view);
        dialogLineWidth = currentAlertDialog.create();
        dialogLineWidth.setTitle("Set Line Width");
        dialogLineWidth.show();
    }
}
```